# Android: animated text inside edittext

Tags: android, animation, android-edittext

Is there any way to animate text inside edittext? In my app i use editetext to show and edit some info.

Comment: find this https://github.com/alphamu/AnimatedEditText

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can put animation to any view. Text inside EditText is not a view. It is a string. We can give animation yo whole EditText but not to a string.

Thanks
Deepak

Answer (score 1):

Nop :), you can't animate text, but you can animate whole edittext inside some layout. So for example if you want you can put linearlayout as wrapper to the edittext and animate the edittext.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do movement animations. But you can use spans to animate the text and use a `ValueAnimator` or `ObjectAnimator` to animate the values in the spans.

Comment: do you have any example?